# How can i change the name of databases in redis?

Tags: database, redis, nosql

How can i change the name of databases in redis? Example:

```
Db01
  key01
  key02

Db02
  key01
  key02

Db03
  key01
  key02
```

i want to change db01 name or db02, db03 to other names

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Redis databases are identified by an integer index, there is no database name.

By default there are 16 databases, indexed from 0 to 15.

Check the following article: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/cheatsheets/how-to-manage-redis-databases-and-keys

Comment: This makes me sad.