# How to specify Redis database name in connection string in ASP.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, redis, stackexchange.redis

I am trying to register Redis connection string in my .Net Core 3.1 WebAPI. We have been provided with hostname, port, password and database name. We are using StackExchange Redis client. I checked their Github documentation and there is option to provide DefaultDatabase={int}. But how to specify database name? I tried connecting through RedisInsight and it works fine. In RedisInsight, its accepting it as logical database name. But I am unable to figure out which param on connectionstring will accept database name.

```
services.AddStackExchangeRedisCache(options =>
{
    options.Configuration = "redishostname:12345,password=mypwd";
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis select different database than db0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48556175/microsoft-extensions-caching-redis-select-different-database-than-db0)

Comment: Not fully. I am aware of the configuration DefaultDatabase={int} (I have mentioned it in the question as well). But that expects me to pass an integer i.e. the database number. I only have the database name at this time.

Comment: Already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/35932972/384464